# How to change JSON content, that is in another file, with javascript inside html?

Tags: javascript, html, json

So just code for fun, but I am stuck here. Basically I want to make a HTML app (don't worry about this part) and I want to change JSON content (that is in another file) to be the value of the `<input>`.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PassMan</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var User = document.getElementById('1');
      var Pass = document.getElementById('2');
      var Acc = document.getElementById('3');

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <button type="button" onclick="newPass()">Add pass</button>
      <input id="1" name="" value="Username">
      <input id="2" type="text" value="Pass">
      <input id="3" value="Social account">
    </form>
</body>
```

I want this - When the button is pressed, tha value of the three inputs go to JSON file as a new object.

Comment: JavaScript at the client-side is not designed to write to files. You'd need to save the JSON file at the server-side.

Comment: You cannot access any client-side files in Javascript from the browser.

Comment: assuming the json file is on the server, you'd have to make an ajax request to a server-side script which would modify the file. If the file is on the local (user's) machine, then forget about it, you can't modify it. BTW if you've got to the situation where you're thinking about updating your JSON, it's not so easy (it's just a text format after all). Maybe you really need a database?

Comment: Yes I do. Are there any others, compatible with javascript @ADyson

Comment: You can't access a database directly from browser-based Javascript. You need an API written in some server-side language (e.g. PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby, NodeJS etc) which you make HTTP requests to, and that script interacts with the database and sends your webpage the response to display.